# What's different when DocumentRoot and Directory is in/outside VirtualHost in Apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

What's the difference between these two cases:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
  ServerName localhost
  DocumentRoot "/home/sfprojects/jobeet/web"
  DirectoryIndex index.php
  <Directory "/home/sfprojects/jobeet/web">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and simply:

```
  DocumentRoot "/home/sfprojects/jobeet/web"
  DirectoryIndex index.php
  <Directory "/home/sfprojects/jobeet/web">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>
```

Seems both work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't keep it in a virtualhost, then it will be applied to localhost automatically.

It should be inside VirtualHost if you are using named virtual hosts and when you want your virtualhost (i.e., jobeet) to serve a different path from the main host (i.e., localhost) 
Otherwise subdomain.domain.com will be the SAME site as domain.com

The Directory directive should be with a documentroot to define the access rights.

virtual hosts allow you to create "fake" sites like mysite.dev or host other domains from one server.

Comment: Can I put both `maindomain` and `subdomain` into virtual host?

Comment: Yes, you can. I only have virtual hosts.